# Pandas: when can I directly assign to values array

Tags: python, pandas

I was messing with pandas in the interpreter and the following behavior took me by surprise:

```
>>> data2 = [[1, np.nan], [2, -17]]
>>> f2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
>>> f2
   0     1
0  1   NaN
1  2 -17.0
>>> f2.values[1, 1] = -99.0
>>> f2
   0     1
0  1   NaN
1  2 -17.0
>>> type(f2.values[0, 0]), type(f2.values[1, 0])
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>)
```

I am unable to assign directly to the underlying array using the values attribute.  However, if I explicitly start with floats, I can:

```
>>> data = [[1.0, np.nan], [2.0, -17.0]]
>>> f = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> f
     0     1
0  1.0   NaN
1  2.0 -17.0
>>> f.values[1, 1] = -99.0
>>> f
     0     1
0  1.0   NaN
1  2.0 -99.0
```

Does anyone know a rule that would have allowed me to predict this?  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, so this is not an answer. But I would never get `.values` before assigning: I would do `f.iloc[1, 1] = -99.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does not guarantee when assignments to `df.values` affect `df`, so I would recommend *never* trying to modify `df` via `df.values`. How and when this works is an implementation detail. As [StevenG states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693521/190597), use `df.iloc[1,1] = -99` to assign a new value at a location specified by ordinal indices, or use `df.set_value` to assign a new value at a location specified by index labels.

Under the hood, `df` stores its values in "blocks". The blocks are segregated by
dtype, though sometimes more than one block can have the same dtype. The data in
each block is stored in a NumPy array.

When you use

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan], [2, -17]])
```

The first column has integer dtype while the second column has floating point dtype.

```
In [27]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
1    1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 112.0 bytes
```

When you access the `df2.values` property, a *single* NumPy array of one homogenous dtype is returned. When
the `df2` has columns of different dtypes, Pandas must promote the dtypes to a
single common dtype. In the worst case, the common dtype may be `object`. In this
case, the integers are promoted to floating point dtype.

```
In [28]: df2.values.dtype
Out[28]: dtype('float64')
```

The dtype promotion requires that the underlying data from the various blocks be
*copied* into a new NumPy array. Thus, modifying the copy returned by
`df2.values` does not affect the original data in `df2`.

In contrast, if the DataFrame's data is entirely of one dtype, then `f.values`
returns a view of the original data. So in this special case, modifying
`f.values` affects `f` itself.

---

To summarize, when a DataFrame contains multiple blocks, `df.values` will be a
copy of the data in `df`. Modifying the copy in `df.values` will not affect
`df`.

Since a DataFrame can sometimes have multiple blocks of the *same dtype*, even
if all the data in the DataFrame has the same dtype, `df.values` may still be a
copy.

If you call [`df.consolidate()`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L2802) then data of each dtype will be grouped together
in a single NumPy array. So if your DataFrame's data consists of a single dtype,
and you call `df.consolidate()` first, then modifying `df.values` will modify
`df`.

Answer (score 0):

using .values returns a numpy array. so whatever you do after doing `df.values` will be exactly like using a numpy array.

using`df.iloc[i,i]` allows you to set values or extract value using an integer position